# odbcDriverConnect fails as Microsoft enforce multi-factor authentication

Tags: azure-sql-database, odbc, rodbc

We have been using RODBC odbcDriverConnect for several years to access Azure SQL database using AD Username Password authentication.

This now fails with the following error, after Microsoft have enforced multi-factor authentication.

```
    Warning messages:
1: In RODBC::odbcDriverConnect(sprintf(dbs, db, xOPTmisc::xopt_f_keyring_key_get(kr_service,  :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state FA004, code 0, message [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Failed to authenticate the user 'simon.harrison@xelocity.com' in Active Directory (Authentication option is 'ActiveDirectoryPassword').
Error code 0xCAA2000C; state 10
AADSTS50076: Due to a configuration change made by your administrator, or because you moved to a new location, you must use multi-factor authentication to access '022907d3-0f1b-48f7-badc-1ba6abab6d66'.
Trace ID: 55600fce-c192-4252-ba62-2876535d5000
Correlation ID: d5a4a741-31cd-46d7-8dbc-4c9a9278a680
Timestamp: 2023-05-11 04:53:33Z
2: In RODBC::odbcDriverConnect(sprintf(dbs, db, xOPTmisc::xopt_f_keyring_key_get(kr_service,  :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state 01S00, code 0, message [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid connection string attribute
3: In RODBC::odbcDriverConnect(sprintf(dbs, db, xOPTmisc::xopt_f_keyring_key_get(kr_service,  :
  ODBC connection failed
```

Is there any known work-around for this?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the scenario in my environment and faced a similar error and while researching on It I found out that the user I am using to log into the SQL server with Active Directory password authentication would have configured with some default security measures. Those were the ones prohibiting me to log in without multi-factor authentication.

To resolve this,

- **First Go to Azure active directory >> Properties >> Disable security defaults.**
  [image]
- **Even when Security defaults are disabled check if any conditional access policies which is prompting you from additional authentication.**
  [image]

After disabling security defaults and removing conditional access policy I am successfully able to connect with the SQL database.

**My Code:**

```r
library(RODBC)

server <- "servername.database.windows.net"
database <- "db name"
user <- "UID"
password <- "password"
authentication <- "ActiveDirectoryPassword"

connection_string <- paste0(
  "Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};",
  "Server=", server, ";",
  "Database=", database, ";",
  "Authentication=", authentication, ";",
  "UID=", user, ";",
  "PWD=", password,";",
  "Encrypt=yes",
  ";Port=1433"
)

conn <- odbcDriverConnect(connection_string)
print("connected")

odbcClose(conn)
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you can't do as @pratik suggests, then you have to use ActiveDirectoryInteractive or SQLPassword authentication.
With ActiveDirectoryInteractive you can pass a username, but Password and multi-factor authentication are then done via Microsoft dialog windows.  This is typically required just once for a Azure SQL server in a 'session'. (But unclear what constitutes a session.  Restarting R starts a new session.)

Note: that bcp utility can also use MFA if you pass it the -G (Azure authentication) argument with just a -U username.  However this requires password and MFA authentication to be done for **EVERY** file uploaded.  This is a major problem for bcp users.